# How to check the type of an MDX expression?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am creating some tool to dynamically generating MDX queries. In a part of the query I am generating I need to check whether an expression is a member expression or tuple expression and apply different logic on it. Does anyone have any clue about how I can check the MDX expression type at run time by just using MDX?

Comment: What do you mean by type ? A member is a tuple; perhaps you should briefly mention what you want to do once you got the "type".

Comment: @MarcPolizzi "A member is a tuple" is not true. What is true is that in many places Analysis Services allows you to be sloppy and use a member where a tuple is expected, and does an implicit type conversion.

Comment: @FrankPl yes there are some functions only applies on members, not on tuples.

Comment: @FrankPI : agree with you but what would be the logic that can be applied to a member and not a tuple (and vice versa) - this in the same place of the MDX expression ?

Comment: @MarcPolizzi E. g. properties like `.Name` as well as functions like `.Lag()` can only be applied to members, not to tuples, and will cause an error, at least if you have a 'multidimensional tuple', i. e. one that contains members from at least two hierarchies. I agree that the other way round, applying a method that uses a tuple to a member is handled with automatic type casting.

Answer (score 1):

To know the exact type of an MDX expression, you would have to write an MDX parser (at least for the expressions that can appear).

There are some rules: something like `(x, y)` is probably a tuple; and the result of all methods that return a tuple (like `StrToTuple`, `Root`, or `Item`, the latter only if applied to a set) is a tuple, and the result of all methods that return a member (like `Ancestor` or `DefaultMember`, but also `Item` if applied to a tuple) is a member. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145970.aspx for a list of functions classified by type. But you see already the difficulty of the `Item` method which can either deliver a tuple, or a member, depending on context.

And I would not think that you can easily write an MDX statement that tests the type, as Analysis Services uses automatic type casting which converts a member to a tuple whenever the context needs one.

The best approach from my point of view would be to use syntax that allows both a member and a tuple being used, and to avoid having to know the type.

One approach that could work as well without need to explicitly checking for data type, but just checking if some construct is valid or not would be using the VBA function `IsError` as follows:

```
IIf(IsError(x.Level, <something avoiding the Level function>, <use x.Level>)
```

Comment: @FrankPI Thanks for your answer. I hit some issue that some expression checks whether there are multiple levels on rows or columns but some times the user could have tuples in rows/columns. And some functions which are used are not applicable to tuples (e.g. LEVEL as from your link). That's why I want to know the type of the expression. It seems from your answer that I have to make the generator know more things about what is passed in. I guess that is what I have to do for now to fix this issue unfortunately.

Comment: @bigbearzhu I added another approach at the end of my answer. But not knowing your exact problem, I am not sure if it helps for that or not.

Comment: @FrankPI sounds like a possible work around to me! I will have a try. Thanks a lot for that.